# How do I set Puyo Puyo 2 to English?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, sega-3d-classics-collection, puyo-puyo-2

I fired up my copy of Sega 3D Classics Collection on my Nintendo 3DS and loaded up Puyo Puyo 2. I noticed that the game text displays in Japanese. I'm using the USA version of the game cartridge on a USA 3DS with the console language set to English, and none of the other games on the cartridge display in anything other than English.

How do I set the language of Puyo Puyo 2 to English?

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot, and it appears that the game wasn't completely translated in English, that's why you have Japanese menus.

I found [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/puyopop/comments/7gye3v/kinda_disappointed_with_sega_3d_classics/), and OP is complaining that:

> All Japanese text has not been translated. (including the how to play section..)

There are also Puyo Puyo 2's [gameplay videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXtqUcMzwEA) showing that the game has clearly some text still untraslated.